# Как вывести на экран строку LPTSTR?

Tags: c, winapi

Добрый вечер!

Не могу вывести на экран строку LPTSTR... Вот код:

```
char *buffer[UNLEN + 1];  // буфер
DWORD size;               // размер
size = sizeof(buffer);    // размер буфера
if (GetUserName((LPWSTR) buffer, &size) == 0)
    printf("Error GetUserName"); // при ошибке функция вернет 0

printf("%s", buffer);

getch();
return 0;
```

Выводится только 1-я буква... В чем ошибка? И вот какой функцией можно вывести на экран диапазон доступных адресов памяти?

Спасибо!

Comment: Не надо писать больше одного знака вопроса.

Comment: А что такое "доступный адрес памяти"? (И зачем он вам?) Вот текущий stack frame -- он доступен? А выделенные байт heap? А невыделенные?

Comment: Сам вот гадаю, задание в лабе такое... Может это оперативна память.

Comment: ХэшКод,  ОК.

Comment: @Alerr: ну вот мы все тоже гадаем.

Comment: @mega: (там комментарии кончились) не-а, не угадали. Посмотрите внимательно на 3-ю строку ответа и время последнего редактирования.

Comment: >Посмотрите внимательно на 3-ю строку ответа и время последнего редактирования.

Не понял, что Вы имели ввиду. Я смотрю на Ваш ответ. Не суть. Я просто смеюсь. Еще `size` нужно было скорректировать, это да, Вы верно подметили: `GetUserName` принимает размер в `TCHAR'ах`, а не в байтах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эээ... Ну вы даёте! `(LPWSTR)buffer` -- так делать нельзя. Жёсткий C-шный каст.

Попробуйте так:

1. `WCHAR buffer[UNLEN+1]`
2. size = UNLEN + 1;
3. `wprintf(L"%s",buffer)`

Дело в том, что `LPWSTR` -- это указатель на строку из длинных символов. Вы же завели строку из обычных, а функции `GetUserName` наврали, что она из длинных. Обманывать нехорошо. Функция записала в вашу область памяти (возможно, с переполнением, потому что размер-то ваш в коротких символах!) длинные символы, а теперь функция `printf`, понятно, не может ничего вывести.

Comment: ругается на %s

Comment: @Alerr: а, ну да, исправил. Надо было `L`.

Comment: И почему при приписывании L перестает ругаться, уже который раз эту "L" в программах замечаю.

Comment: @Alerr: потому что без `L` это строка коротких символов, однобайтных. А с `L` -- строка двухбайтных. `wprintf` хочет именно такую.

Comment: А можно где-то очень подробно об этом почитать? Просто уже много времени вожусь и таких основ вне знаю...

Comment: @Alerr: вот вроде ничего, но на английском: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win32-Chara

Comment: `GetUserName` транслируется в 2 сигнатуры: `GetUserNameA( LPCSTR ...)` и `GetUserNameW( LPCWSTR ... )`. Поэтому передавать ей указатель на `WCHAR` некорректно, впринципе!  

Если уж используете `WCHAR`, то используйте и соответствующую функцию. А для `ANSI`-версии кода @Alerr'а достаточно было просто изменить `GetUserName` на `GetUserNameA`.

Comment: @mega: насчёт достаточности не уверен: посмотрите, как декларируется `buffer`. Кроме того, я бы лично не рекомендовал писать для ANSI-таргета, 21 столетие на дворе всё же.

Comment: >насчёт достаточности не уверен: посмотрите, как декларируется buffer

Ага, вижу:

    char *buffer[UNLEN + 1];

нужно заменить на: 

    char buffer[UNLEN + 1];

Только ведь Вы тоже это только что заметили. :) Иначе бы так не писали:

>Вы же завели строку из обычных

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать так

```
(GetUserName((LPWSTR)buffer,&sizeof(buffer))==0)
```

Comment: ругается на sizeof

Comment: это понятно, откуда ж у `sizeof(...)` адрес?